# repeated results with Views Slideshow results and commerce products

Tags: views, commerce, javascript

I have a slideshow view where I am showing most recently discounted items.

each product display has 8 different variable combinations therefore, 8 product SKUs connected to the product content.

I have my view filtering by Content:product. However, it is showing all 8 products for each piece content.

[image]

Comment: What is the base table for your view? Content or Commerce Product?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to make sure that the relationship is set to be required, if the duplicate results still coming on .. go to views query settings and check both DISTINCT and PURE DISTINCT